# Dynamic data segregation

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a framework in SQL ( tables mainly ) which could help to me segregate SQL data dynamically based on user roles.

e.g. User with role A should have access to data from country XYZ

I have bunch of stored procedures which fetch different attributes of data now I am trying to update stored procedures in a way that stored procedures needs to be modified only once.

I might get different filter criteria in future so I am trying to create a matrix of filter conditions which could be read in stored procedure dynamically to filter data.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: How about a user-country cross reference table?  That way your input parameter to your procedure can just be something that identifies your user, then within the body of your `SELECT` statement, `JOIN` that cross reference table before you get to the tables with your actual data, so the filtering you desire will happen.

Comment: Depending on the DBMS you don't need stored procedures for this. In Postgres 9.5 you could use row level security for this. Oracle offers "virtual private databases" and SQL Server also has something similar (don't know the name right now)

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I am using SQL server 2012. @LDMJoe, Country filter is one example there are multiple other dimensions which could be used for data slicing.